# Maintain maxRecordCount when updating hosted feature service on ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, hosted-feature-layer

I have a hosted layer in ArcGIS Online, and I've updated its `maxRecordCount` value as per the instructions at https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012383

`Max Record Count: 25000`

Whenever I update that hosted layer (either via the ArcGIS Pro [Overwrite Web Layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/overview/overwrite-a-web-layer.htm) tool or via [Python](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/api-python/analytics/updating-your-hosted-feature-services-with-arcgis-pro-and-the-arcgis-api-for-python/)), the value reverts to the default of 2,000 features.

How can I maintain the changed `maxRecordCount` value when updating a hosted feature layer in ArcGIS Online?

Comment: The number may exceed the maximum maximum. 25K is a huge number of features to burden someone else's server with.  If you have you own Server, you might be able to get it that high, but you might regret it.

Comment: @Vince yep, we've tested the performance and 25k works fine. So the question is how to preserve that value after updating the layer

Comment: Overwrite deletes the previous service, so when you reset the service, it uses default values. You'll need to make the same modifications after reset or include the massive feature count in the overwriting definition.

Comment: @vince Do you want to put that as an answer and i'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Vince's comment it seems that re-publishing the layer to ArcGIS Online unavoidably resets the `maxRecordCount`.

The workaround is to change the value again after re-publishing, either manually or [programatically](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404450/how-to-change-the-service-definition-of-an-arcgis-online-layer-via-python/).